# How can you perform Cox regression on a dataset with time to event data?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have a dataset for a n = 200 hardware components. The dataset consists of some covariates describing its size, working conditions etc as well as its StartTime and EndTime.

Components that have failed in operation will also have a FailTime and some observations will be right censored. So for each row in the dataset there will be p = 8 covariates and a time to failure (TTF) measurement, if the component failed.

My question is, can you fit a Cox regression model between the TTF response and the covariates? The Cox regression model seems to only apply to the hazard function but is it possible to extend it for this type of problem? Or maybe I can compute an estimated hazard value for each observation using the TTF values?

Any tips would be much appreciated.